# Query for list rows that has multiple row match

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables for e-commerce website, I'm trying to apply a filter for listed items,

Table 1: `items` has `item_id`, `item_name`

Table 2: `inputs` has `input_value`, `item`, `spec`

I need to do a query like this, so I can get all items that have the color red and size 38:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM items
     , inputs
 WHERE inputs.item = items.item_id
   AND inputs.spec='color' 
   AND inputs.input_value = 'red'
   AND inputs.spec = 'size' 
   AND inputs.input_value='38'
```

Comment: *I need to do query like this...*  Okay, I see the query, what's wrong with it?  What is the error message?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score -2):

The first thing that comes in mind is [MySQL INTERSECT](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/intersect.php)

**EDIT**: Just to give a bit more credit to the response. On the linked site they gave a way to do the query in the "MySQL way" by using the IN clause. Not sure if the is the best way to do it though.

```sql
SELECT items.item_id, items.item_name
FROM items, inputs
WHERE inputs.item = items.item_id
  AND inputs.spec = 'color' AND inputs.input_value = 'red'
  AND items.item_id IN
   (SELECT items.item_id
    FROM items, inputs
    WHERE inputs.item = items.item_id
      AND inputs.spec = 'size' AND inputs.input_value = '38');
```

**OLD**: As someone pointed out this does not works sadly :(

I did not run it personally but it should look something like this in your case:

```sql
SELECT items.item_id, items.item_name FROM items, inputs
  WHERE inputs.item = items.item_id
    AND inputs.spec = 'color' AND inputs.input_value = 'red'
INTERSECT
SELECT items.item_id, items.item_name FROM items, inputs
  WHERE inputs.item = items.item_id
    AND inputs.spec = 'size' AND inputs.input_value = '38'
```

The first query gets all the items that have a `color` input with value `red`.
The second query gets all the items that have a `size` input with value `38`.
Then the INTERSECT operator return every items that were returned by both queries.

If you know the mathematical intersections on sets. It is basically the same.

Comment: Why do you link to a page that's nothing to do with MySQL?

Comment: Oh yeah... You are totally right. I read it too fast. I guess I was too eager to respond. Anyway this shouldn't work then.

Comment: That's probably why a delete button is provided